# magento 2 simple block firing exception Invalid template file

Tags: magento2

i'm new at magento 2 and i want to add some simple html to my header but i cant get to work, i have a simple theme that overrides blank theme from magento and i create the folder Magento_Theme and also this simple default.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configration.xsd">
  <referenceContainer name="header.panel"> <!-- the name of the container you want to insert into -->
    <container name="new_container" htmlClass="container_css_class" htmlTag="div">
      <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" template="Magento_Theme::template/template.phtml" name="block_name" />
    </container>
  </referenceContainer>
</page>
```

and i have this simple template in the folder Magento_Theme\template\template.phtml

```
<div class="block" style="float: right;">
 <?php echo __('Custom Line'); ?>
</div>
```

but the magento keep firing this error

```
1 exception(s):
Exception #0 (Magento\Framework\Exception\ValidatorException): Invalid 
template file: 'Magento_Theme::template/template.phtml' in module: '' 
block's name: 'block_name'
```

im using magento 2.2.5

Answer (score 2):

Try rename your folder 'template' to 'templates' (add 's') and make it like this

template="Magento_Theme::template.phtml"

Comment: Ah this has gotten me a couple of times!

Answer (score 0):

I found the error the Magento_Theme:: is a path to templates folder and when i changed my template.phtml for the folder templates and change Magento_theme::template/template.php to Magento_theme::template.php it worked